# Steam games suddenly stopped launching

Tags: games, steam

So, I have steam downloaded from the ubuntu software center and have been playing antichamber, which is linux enabled and doesn't require wine/playonlinux or anything to run. It used to run absolutely fine, launched no problem. Suddenly it won't do anything: I click the 'play' button, and a little 'running' message shows next to the name for a few seconds. Sometimes the screen distorts a little so that it looks like the game might open (you know how when you launch a game what's on the screen distorts a little before the actual game starts running), but then it doesn't. No error message, nothing, the running message disappears. Same thing happens when I try to launch the Stanley Parable, which is also linux enabled.

I tried backing up my game files, uninstalling and reinstalling steam, same thing happens. I can't find the `clientregistry.blob` file (and I did check using hidden files and everything). What's going on? This just started happening one day and I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** Result of entering command 'steam' in terminal

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
[0614/121654:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[0614/121655:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160609205521)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465505721)
[0614/121658:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160609205521)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1465507923)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
roaming config store loaded successfully - 906 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: ""/home/tea/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam" "
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
System startup time: 44.41 seconds
Generating new string page texture 74: 1024x256, total string texture memory is 1.36 MB
Generating new string page texture 75: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131.07 KB
Generating new string page texture 76: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.49 MB
Generating new string page texture 77: 64x256, total string texture memory is 1.56 MB
Generating new string page texture 78: 32x256, total string texture memory is 1.59 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1465507923)
CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2
Generating new string page texture 84: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1.72 MB
Generating new string page texture 85: 384x256, total string texture memory is 2.11 MB
Generating new string page texture 86: 2048x256, total string texture memory is 4.21 MB
Generating new string page texture 89: 512x256, total string texture memory is 4.73 MB
Game update: AppID 219890 "Antichamber", ProcID 14490, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/tea/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/tea/.steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Generating new string page texture 107: 24x256, total string texture memory is 4.76 MB
Generating new string page texture 109: 256x256, total string texture memory is 393.22 KB
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 219890
dlopen failed trying to load:
/home/tea/.steam/linux32/libsteam.so
with error:
/home/tea/.steam/linux32/libsteam.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198078908482 [API loaded no]
```

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Open up a terminal and launch steam from the terminal, the command is just 'steam' I believe. Then attempt to launch the game through steam. Hopefully some debug messages will appear on terminal. I'm not sure what the command is to directly run your game, but you should try launching your game from terminal and reading the messages as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me and you never reboot, you may want to start there(I know, I shouldn't be saying that when it comes to a linux machine).

If you've had any kernel updates and not rebooted, there could be a conflict between the graphics driver kernel module and kernel version.

Comment: I rebooted everything this morning, usually it fixes things but this time it unfortunately did not.

Answer (score 0):

Well Mate I've had a similar trouble, Hope this helps, as your query doesn't clarify on the error is either on the client side or system site. Try fresh install or check for these [steam won't open](https://www.onlineprivacytips.co/guides/fix-steam-wont-open/) remedies as sometimes updates may flickr the launch.